# Convergence of $\sum_{r=1}^n \frac {1}{r^p (n-r+1)^p}$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the sequence $\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r^p (n-r+1)^p}$ converges as $n\to\infty$ if $p\ge\frac{1}{2}$ and diverges if $p<\frac{1}{2}$.

My attempt:

[image]

Here I bound the sequence from below by $\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{(\frac{n+2}{2})^{2p}}$ which diverges if $p <\frac12$. So the given sequence diverges for $p< \frac{1}{2}$. But how do we show the convergence claim?

Comment: Does $n$ approaches to $\infty $?

Comment: yes, pls see edited above

Comment: When $p=\frac {1}{2} $, the series does not have to be divergent. The right side of the inequality written in Latex is simply 2 when $p=\frac {1}{2} $.

Comment: Now, multiply the two inequalities $k\geq 1$ and $n \geq k$ to get $f(k)\geq n $. Then it follows that the series is convergent if $p>1$.

Comment: if $p = 1/2$ then (givenseries ) $\geq \sum \frac{2}{n+2} >\sum 2$ which is constant series andso it diverges. 

My question is if given series say $f(n) \geq g(n)$ where $g(n) = \sum \frac{2^{2p}}{(n+2)^{2p}}$ , g(n) diverges, due to fact that $f(n) \geq g(n)$ , f(n) diverges.

If g(n) converges as we have $f(n) \geq g(n)$, we can not say any thing about f(n) convergence. But in solution it is given that if $p> 1/2$ given series converges which i did not understand. Sure that i am missing some where

Comment: Why $\sum \frac {2}{2+n}>\sum 2$?Note that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac {2}{n+2}=\frac {2n}{n+2}$. To answer your question, you have to show that $p\geq \frac {1}{2}$ is necessary AND sufficient condition for the given series to be divergent.

Comment: OK  i am mistaken. let $a_n = \frac {2^{2p}}{(n+2)^{2p}} = \frac {2^{2p}}{n^{2p}(1+\frac{2}{n})^{2p}}, b_n = \frac{1}{n^{2p}}, \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 2^{2p}$ by limit comparision test and p-test , given series $\sum a_n$ converges if p>(1/2) and diverges if p<(1/2). But my doubt is $\sum c_n$ maximum value is series $\sum a_n$. But $\sum c_n \leq \sum a_n$.

Comment: i mean to say $f(n) \leq g(n)$ then we can talk about f(n) convergence and not divergence. So if $c_n < a_n$ which $a_n$ is max value of $c_n$, $a_n$ converges gives $c_n$ convergence and $a_n$ divergence does mean nothing to $c_n$ divergence.

Comment: Exactly. That is why I have given a minimum value of f as $n $.

Comment: Ok now i understood it. thnx for enlightening me

Answer (score 1):

Using the AM-GM Inequality 
$ \frac {1} {r^p (n-r+1)^p}  \leq 1/2 (\frac {1} {r^{2p}} + \frac {1} {(n-r+1)^{2p}}) $

Summing we get that the right side of the inequality is
$ \sum_{r=1}^n (\frac {1}{r^{2p}}) $

This converges for $ p>\frac{1}{2} $.

Similarly, using AM-GM Inequality,
$ \frac {1} {r^p (n-r+1)^p}  \geq 2/({r^{2p}} + { (n-r+1)^{2p}}) $

A lower bound on this is 
 $ \sum_{r=(n+1)/2}^{n+1} \frac {1}{r^{2p}} $

~ $  = \sum_{r=(n+1)/2}^{n+1}  {{(n)}^{1-2p}} \frac {1}{n} 
\frac {1}{ {(\frac {r} {n})}^{2p}} $

~ $  {{(n)}^{1-2p}} \int_{\frac {1}{2}}^{1} \frac {1}{{x}^{2p} } 
 dx $ using Riemann Sums.

This is unbounded as $ {n \to \infty} $ if $ p < \frac {1} {2} $

This still leaves the question of $ p = \frac {1} {2} $

In this case, regarding the series up to $ n $ as a Riemann Sum we get
$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} \ dx
$

Using the substitution $ x = sin^{2} ({\theta}) $ we see that this is finite. So, the series converges for $ p = \frac {1} {2} $